# Why didn't Zathras react to seeing Delenn the same way he reacted to seeing Sheridan and Sinclair?

Tags: babylon-5

In *War Without End, Part 1*, Zathras comes aboard the White Star (stumbling into another Minbari). He sees Sinclair and excitedly approaches. After a bit of back and forth, this exchange happens:

> **Zathras:** Zathras honored to meet you for *many* reasons. Zathras also honored to meet *you* [turns to Sheridan] for other reasons.
>
> **Sheridan:** Uh, such as?
>
> **Zathras:** [Clicks a sound of disapproval] Oh no, Draal gave Zathras list of things not to say; this was one. [Zathras realizes what he's said] No. Hm, not good. Not supposed to mention One or The One.

As we find out by the end of the two-parter:

> Sinclair, Delenn, Sheridan are collectively "The One", being The One Who Was, The One Who Is, and The One That Will Be respectively.

Delenn was present at the beginning of the scene, so why doesn't Zathras react to her in the same way? I suppose it's possible that they have met before, but she says that Draal is "sending an aide" and doesn't refer to him by name, and the look she gives Zathras makes it seem like she doesn't recognize him. So why does Zathras ignore Delenn when she was with Sinclair and Sheridan?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you watch the scene very closely, you'll notice that **Delenn was never in Zathras' field of vision**!

When Zathras arrives, he walks backwards away from the Minbari crewman he crashed into and is focused on him. Delenn, initially standing by Sheridan and Sinclair, looks with concern and approaches. In the next shot, she is behind Zathras, who is still focused on the crewman. Then Zathras finally turns away and, without looking at Delenn behind him, sees Sinclair and Sheridan.

[image: Zathras does not see Delenn]

Zathras excitedly approaches Sinclair and never looks back. Eventually, Delenn walks away with the Minbari crewman. So in this entire scene, Zathras never actually saw Delenn, and therefore didn't react to her the same way he reacted to the other two.

I'd certainly like to think that the director of the episode, Mike Vejar, intentionally made it this way to enhance the surprise at the end of the two-parter and avoid a narrative cheat.